# Does the current have to be zero by the end of the circuit?

Tags: arduino

From my understanding, current goes from Ground to Positive.

Thus, lets say I connect my Arduino's 5v pin to a light's positive wire, then Ground to the light's negative wire, does the current need to be at zero before it reaches the 5v pin to not damage it?

To me it makes no sense because the 5v pin is asking for x amount of current but it cannot handle the x amount of current it asked for. Can someone explain this to me?

I tried looking it up but I cant seem to search for the right words, or there may not be an answer because it may be a noob/common knowledge question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about electrical engineering/electronics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no parallel paths, then the current is the same everywhere in the circuit. It's the voltage that drops from 5 volts to 0 volts from positive to ground in the circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Its starting to make more sense. So does the voltage need to be at zero at the end of the circuit to not damage it?

Comment: @KevinDuarte - The voltage at the ground terminal is zero by definition. The voltage at the positive terminal is relative to the voltage defined to be zero volts at the ground terminal. Damage to the circuit would be related to excessive current, which in turn would be related to insufficient resistance in the circuit. You might want to post a question like this at some physics forum.